# How do I delete paragraphs of a certain language?

Tags: vba, macos, ms-word, non-english

I wish to delete Simplified Chinese text in a document with both English and Chinese. The documents don't have any set pattern for which paragraphs are in which language.

I tried a few versions of code that search by paragraph and by language.

```vb
Sub DeleteCN()
    iParCount = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    For J = 1 To iParCount
        sMyPar = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J).Range.Text
        If sMyPar.WdLanguageID = wdSimplifiedChinese Then
            sMyPar.Delete
        End If
    Next J
End Sub
```

The error I get with this latest attempt is that an object is required on the If line.

Comment: Very good first question. You were clear and concise and include a code example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few issues with your code.

1) The most serious is you must reverse your loop. The loop must be reversed because as you delete a paragraph the number of paragraphs will dynamically change and then future paragraphs will no longer exist.

2) The rest are syntax errors, you can see where the syntax has been updated in the code. If you declare your variables it will be easier to know the correct syntax.

```
Sub DeleteCN()

Dim iParaCount As Integer
Dim para As Paragraph

iParaCount = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

For J = iParaCount To 1 Step -1
    Set para = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(J)
    If para.Range.LanguageID = wdSimplifiedChinese Then
        para.Range.Delete
    End If
Next J

End Sub
```

Hope this helps.